# rTorrent Docker container failing to start, saying std::bad_alloc

Tags: docker, archlinux, bittorrent

I have been running rTorrent in a docker stack on my home server for some time, but after a recent update to the Arch Linux host I have been unable to get it to launch. The only error I can get from it is "rtorrent: std::bad_alloc" and nothing else. I assume the issue is caused by one of the updated packages but since some 400 packages were updated it would be impossible to tell which.

I have tried several different distributions and containers with rtorrent in them, all of them have the same issue. However, all variants I tested run fine on bare metal. I tried making custom containers with nothing but rtorrent in them and had the same problem. I tested the containers on a different machine (WSL2 Ubuntu) with the same configuration, images, and compose files and they launch just fine. I double checked RAM and storage and both are far from capacity.

Additionally, all tested containers work in podman again with no changes. I am temporarily running them under podman but would like to go back to docker due to a some configuration constraints. I can provide any logs for anything as needed but as far as I could tell there was no further output. I am sure a system reimage would fix the problem but I am trying to avoid that as it would be a considerable undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue as you. I took the time to investigate and found this error was thrown when attempting to allocate an array whose [size](https://github.com/rakshasa/libtorrent/blob/91f8cf4b0358d9b4480079ca7798fa7d9aec76b5/src/torrent/poll_epoll.cc#L134) is determined [by the variable _SC_OPEN_MAX](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/blob/1da0e3476dcabbf74b2e836d6b4c37b4d96bde09/src/core/poll_manager.cc#L57).

For some reason, the value has recently changed on my configuration.

What I would suggest is compiling and running the following program on bare metal:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX) << std::endl;
}
```

You will get the value for your system.
Then use this value as maximum when running your container:

```
docker run --rm -v --ulimit nofile=<your-value>:<your-value> your-image ./myapp
```

Or in your docker-compose, at the same level of the image key:

```
ulimits:
    nofile:
        hard: <your-value>
        soft: <your-value>
```

This solved the issue for me.
This [thread on docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/weird-sc-open-max-value/135297/6) will give you further informations.